# Routing in ASP.NET MVC Core, Tag helpers route to wrong POST action

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

In the following example, when I am at `http://test.com/pure-mvc-ui-demo` (note no ID) and post the form, MVC correctly routes to the POST overload of the Example controller action (`http://test.com/pure-mvc-ui-demo`).

When I am at `http://test.com/pure-mvc-ui-demo/1`, the form seemingly incorrectly posts to `http://test.com/pure-mvc-ui-demo/1`, which is not a valid URL for the post overload.

I can circumvent this by using a named route, but I feel MVC should know that there is no such route in a POST context.

Is there a way of mitigating this while still using tag helpers?

CSHTML

```
<form asp-controller="PureMvcUiDemo" asp-action="Example" method="post">
```

Controller

```
    [HttpGet("pure-mvc-ui-demo/{exampleId?}")]
    public IActionResult Example(int? exampleId)
    {
        //...

        return View(exampleViewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost("pure-mvc-ui-demo")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Example(ExampleViewModel exampleViewModel)
    {
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: You can add `asp-route-exampleId=""` to the `<form>`

Comment: You are correct, that does work. Looks messy though :(